# using $(this) with coffee script

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, jquery-file-upload, jquery-fileupload-rails

I am using query file upload.  I have several forms on the page, each identical except for a hidden field called 'project'.  Here is the coffee script that handles the upload:

```
jQuery ->
  $(document).ajaxComplete ->
    $('.project_file').fileupload
      dataType: "script"
      url: ($(this).prev('form').attr("action"))
      paramName: 'file_yo'
      formData: (form) -> 
        [{ name: 'authenticity_token',  value: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}, { name: 'project',value: $(this).prev().val()}]
      alert($(this).prev().val())
      done: (e, data) ->
        $('#finish-text').html "Upload finished"
```

Here is the html for one of the forms.  The only thing that changes from from to form is the value of the hidden field called 'project'.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/projects/6/project_files" class="edit_project" data-remote="true" id="project_file_form" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="iIQXYRJfXRFAaSsvSpb4H+HEUMeAI3pubXDRyd+2Ehk="></div>
    <input id="project" name="project" type="hidden" value="6">
    <input authenticity_token="true" class="field file-field project_file" id="" name="file_yo" title="" type="file" value="">  
</form>
```

The problem is that $(this) is undefined.  When  the alert shows up, it says undefined.  How do I get $(this) to return the specific element with class 'project_file' as it should?

UPDATE:

Here is what the coffee script compiles to:

```
(function() {
  jQuery(function() {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
      return $('.project_file').fileupload({
        dataType: "script",
        url: $(this).prev('form').attr("action"),
        paramName: 'file_yo',
        formData: function(form) {
          return [
            {
              name: 'authenticity_token',
              value: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }, {
              name: 'project',
              value: $(this).prev().val()
            }
          ];
        }
      }, alert($(this).prev().val()));
    });
    return {
      done: function(e, data) {
        return $('#finish-text').html("Upload finished");
      }
    };
  });

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that the options are evaluated when you call `$('.project_file').fileupload()` so even if `$(this)` was what you expect it to, you'd be setting exactly the same `url` on each uploader. I don't think `ajaxComplete` sets any particular context so `this` inside that callback isn't terribly useful on its own.

If you want different options for each instance then you'll have to say so:

```
$('.project_file').each ->
  $(@).fileupload
    #... $(@) should be what you want in here
```

I don't know why you have this bound to `ajaxComplete` but that seems odd at first glance, I'd expect this to be handled directly by `$(document).ready(...)`.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to indent the `alert`, look what your code compiles as:

```
jQuery(function() {
  return $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    return $('.project_file').fileupload({
      dataType: "script",
      url: $(this).prev('form').attr("action"),
      paramName: 'file_yo',
      formData: function(form) {
        return [
          {
            name: 'authenticity_token',
            value: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }, {
            name: 'project',
            value: $(this).prev().val()
          }
        ];
      }
    }, alert($(this).prev().val()), {
      done: function(e, data) {
        return $('#finish-text').html("Upload finished");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thats weird, mine does not compile to that.  I will post what mine compiles to

Comment: @Philip7899 It changes little. Look where your `alert` sits, it is completely wrong at that place. Try indenting it, this is probably what you wanted.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean.  It is indented in my file.  I tried changing the spaces with tabs, but it compiles into the same thing.

Comment: @Philip7899 I suspect you want the `alert` to be inside your `formData` function, I this is the case add two more spaces, if not clearly specify what you need. And: Have a look at your compiled code and check whether you think it is sane.

Comment: The alert is only for debugging purposes.  As you can see, the value parameter is set to "$(this).prev().val()" and i want to make sure that value is correct.

Comment: What do you think `this` is inside an `ajaxComplete` callback?